# Mule getting data from ConsumerIterator

Tags: mule

My mule flow is:

```
<sfdc:query config-ref="SFDC__DevInt" query="dsql:SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = #[flowVars.Name]" doc:name="Salesforce"/>
<logger message="Select query: #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<foreach doc:name="For Each">     
  <logger message="#[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
  <logger message="#[message.payload.Id]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</foreach>
```

Above for loops returns the id. Instead of looping is there any direct way of getting data as iterator object? i.e I need to get the value of id.
Data inside for loops returns:

```
SFDC:Select query: org.mule.streaming.ConsumerIterator@2f23abf
INFO  2015-06-22 13:10:25,520 
{Id=0011100000uPbqeAAC, type=Account}
```

At a time I will be getting single data.

I tried with #[message.payload.iterator().hasNext().next()], but getting

```
Message               : Execution of the expression "message.payload.iterator().hasNext().next()" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: ConsumerIterator
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
```

Comment: i also have similar scenario where inside foreach need to capture id and need to make noe more call to salesfors for each individual id but i'm getting below error:  Execution of the expression "message.payload.hasNext() ? message.payload.next().get('Id') : null" failed.          Root Exception stack trace: [UnexpectedErrorFault [ApiFault exceptionCode='INVALID_OPERATION_WITH_EXPIRED_PASSWORD' exceptionMessage='The users password has expired, you must call SetPassword before attempting any other API operations' extendedErrorDetails='{[0]}' ] ] –

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The message payload after `sfdc:query` is an instance of `org.mule.streaming.ConsumerIterator`, which implements [`java.util.Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Iterator.html). Therefore there's no reason to call `iterator()` on it, it *is* already an iterator.

Moreover `hasNext` returns a boolean, not an `Iterator` instance, so you can't chain the calls as you did.

Your expression should thus be:

```
#[message.payload.hasNext() ? message.payload.next() : null]
```

assuming that `null` is the value you want in case the enumeration is empty.

Comment: #[message.payload.hasNext() ? message.payload.next().get('Id') : null] returns the id value.

Comment: one more question, above flow is in a for loop, how do I continue if the values of message.payload.hasNext() is null? ie. if it is null then for loop should continue to next value.

Comment: `foreach` doesn't have a condition for early exiting (see https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Foreach ). I suggest you use a MEL `expression-component` to have richer flow control.

Comment: instead of null I have made it as: #[message.payload.hasNext() ? message.payload.next() : 'none']. This avoid setting null to payload which causes issue in batch steps.

Comment: got struck, any idea on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684062/mule-batch-commit-message-payload-is-of-type-regularimmutablelist

Comment: Nope. Batch processing is an EE feature: Mulesoft professional support is better equipped to help you, as the source code is not publicly available so I can't peek into anything...

Comment: i also have similar scenario where inside foreach need to capture id and need to make noe more call to salesfors for each individual id but i'm getting below error:  Execution of the expression "message.payload.hasNext() ? message.payload.next().get('Id') : null" failed.          Root Exception stack trace: [UnexpectedErrorFault [ApiFault exceptionCode='INVALID_OPERATION_WITH_EXPIRED_PASSWORD' exceptionMessage='The users password has expired, you must call SetPassword before attempting any other API operations' extendedErrorDetails='{[0]}' ] ] –

Answer (score 2):

You can also convert the iterator into a list if you need to use for-each

`#[org.apache.commons.collections.IteratorUtils.toList(payload)]`